# how remix can deploy my smart contract to the development local Geth (also Ganache) node without a private key

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

I am using remix IDE for developing and testing smart contracts. I also run a Geth node in dev mode by the following command:

```
geth --http --http.corsdomain="http://localhost:8080" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net --vmdebug --datadir /home/mehrdad/eth/data_bc --dev console
```

and in remix environment section I enter IP address of this node (127.0.0.1:port).

I can successfully deploy the contract by just pressing the deploy button (or by running the script `deploy_web3.js`), but I do not understand why It works! because I did not enter my private key in remix. so how does exactly remix sign contract creation transaction? I want a local dev node that is as similar as possible to the main net.

deploy_web3.js

```
// Right click on the script name and hit "Run" to execute
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Running deployWithWeb3 script...')
        
        const contractName = 'Storage' // Change this for other contract
        const constructorArgs = []    // Put constructor args (if any) here for your contract
    
        // Note that the script needs the ABI which is generated from the compilation artifact.
        // Make sure contract is compiled and artifacts are generated
        const artifactsPath = `browser/contracts/artifacts/${contractName}.json` // Change this for different path

        const metadata = JSON.parse(await remix.call('fileManager', 'getFile', artifactsPath))
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    
        let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(metadata.abi)
    
        contract = contract.deploy({
            data: metadata.data.bytecode.object,
            arguments: constructorArgs
        })
    
        const newContractInstance = await contract.send({
            from: accounts[0],
            gas: 1500000,
            gasPrice: '30000000000'
        })
        console.log('Contract deployed at address: ', newContractInstance.options.address)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
  })()
```

Comment: Can you show what the code of deploy_web3.js is?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: I guess there are some accounts already being unlocked when node starts.

Comment: Use `eth_accounts` api to check if there are unlocked accounts

Comment: U need to unlock your account on Geth. But that is the VERY WRONG way